# How to query Moralis roles with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, moralis

I’m checking out Moralis for the first time today. Saw a few of the tutorials and read the documentation. Currently, I’m trying to query the Roles (_Role) but all I get is an empty array.

```
const { fetch: getStaffRole } = useMoralisQuery('_Role');

async function Check() {

  const q = new Moralis.Query('_Role');
  const r = await q.first();
  console.log('w functions:', r); //returns undefined

  const r2 = await getStaffRole();
  console.log('w hooks:', r2); //returns Array []

}
```

[Code snippet of the query, Stack doesn't allow me to directly upload the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFvIv.png)

[—> Table permissions, table, & console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0yxw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify Moralis.Role and to add userMasterKey

```
  const result = await new Moralis.Query(Moralis.Role)
  .equalTo("name", 'admin')
  .first({ useMasterKey: true });
```